# Using a nested for loop in python to print a rectangle

Tags: python

I saw my same question asked but I want to know why what I'm trying isn't working.  This is from a Zybook challenge question.

Here is the exercise:

Write nested loops to print a rectangle. Sample output for given program:

```
* * *  
* * *
```

This is the code I built:

```
num_rows = 2
num_cols = 3

for num_rows in range(0,num_rows):
    for num_cols in range(0,num_cols):
        print('*', end=' ')
    print('')
```

The output is:

```
* * *
* *
```

Question:  Why doesn't the nested for loop print statement iterate for the third time?  When I set the nested loop to:

```
for num_cols in range(0,3):
```

I receive my desired output of the 3x2 asterisk rectangle.  If the num_cols variable is declared as 3, shouldn't the output statement equal my desired output?

Comment: Because you are using the same identifier `num_rows` and `num_cols` for the previously befined variables and the ones used in the `for` loop. Rename the latest ones to something like `row` and `col` instead of `num_rows` and `num_cols`.

Comment: That's it, thank you.  I was scouring my books and I didn't realize that was the error I was making.

Comment: Basically you were overwriting the original `num_rows` and `num_cols` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the num_cols variable by using it as the looping variable as well as the number of columns value. It gets set to 2 during the end of the first iteration of the outer loop. You can replace it with num_col. Same applies for num_rows as well

Answer (score 0):

Following up @Karthik's reasoning of why your code is incorrect, here's a solution with misc. improvements:

```
num_rows = 2
num_cols = 3

for _ in xrange(num_rows):       # xrange for efficient iteration
    for _ in xrange(num_cols):   # no need to unpack iteration variable
        print '*',               # for Python 2, but use the function syntax for 3+
    print ''
```